# Terrible performance, 20secs waiting for ads to display

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, performance

*Hopefully this is correct place to report this*

SO is really sluggish tonight, looking into it a little more there have been many times that I was waiting for nearly 20seconds for the ads to display - see screen shot below from firebug.  The add that displayed was for server fault if it makes any difference.

As far as page rendering is concerned, I had clicked on the questions tab, the page rendered as far as the bottom of the questions and then stops waiting for the ads.  The paging controls and footer do not appear until after the ads have finally rendered.

[image]

Comment: And I thought it was just my internet connection.  Yeah, this is brutal.

Comment: It is pretty repeatable too, just gone back to SO and same thing happened. Always waiting for ads.stackoverflow

Comment: ... and don't try to vote before the ads load, at least not without first taking a precautionary chill pill.

Comment: Happens quite often for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct. We made a change to the ad server which turned out to significantly slow things down - it has been changed back, so performance should be back to where it should be. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer, can confirm it's looking quick and responsive again.